# I need help understanding the problem here

Tags: python, calculator

I'm trying to make an age calculator that is accurate enough to calculate age based on whether the person has had their birth day this year or not.

The problem is something is wrong with my code so even thought when I input "No" it should deduct -1 from the age result but it doesn't do this.

[This is the code that I have wrote so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFpJa.png)

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upper()` makes your text upper case. So the result just can't be 'No'. It should be 'NO'. Also, I recommend you to read about `is` and `==`.

Comment: This is correct, there are two independent errors in this line

Answer (score 1):

```
if Birthday_this_year.upper() is str("No")
```

It's always false, because it doesn't contain lowercase letters.

Comment: I can see what the problem is now thanks a lot